# Perform Click ImageView Android

Tags: android, button, click, imageview

For an ordinary button I can do this:

> myButton.performClick();

and the system understands, that the button was clicked.

Now I have an ImageView. What's the alternative of this function for ImageViews?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still assign an onClickListener to an image view, since the listener assignment method is a View based method. Now once the listener is added to the ImageView, you may call the onClick(ImageView) method in the listener when ever. Besides that, ImageView also has access to the `performClick` method that the ButtonView does. You can use the same code across views so long as you have a Listener.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like..

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // your code here
    }
});
```

Or

In xml:

```
<ImageView  
 android:clickable="true"  
 android:onClick="imageClick"  
 android:src="@drawable/myImage">  
 </ImageView>
```

In code

```
 public class Test extends Activity {  
  ........  
  ........  
 public void imageClick(View view) {  
  //Implement image click function  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `setOnClickListener()` to an `ImageView` as well. You have to make sure you programmatically `imageView.setClickable(true)` first, or in XML define `android:clickable="true"` to your ImageVIew..

Comment: Why? I have listeners set on ImageViews without ether of these properties set.